# How to download all photos and videos stored in iCloud?

Tags: icloud, backup, macos, photos

I'm a mac user. Latest yosemite and itunes installed on my mac. Want to download all data from iCloud photo library and to disable auto upload future. Is there any way to download all photos and videos all at once?

Answer (score 1):

> In iPhoto or Aperture preferences on your Mac, select Photos (or Photo Stream) > My Photo Stream > Automatic Import. All of your photo stream photos will import into your Events, Projects, Photos, Faces, and Places folders in iPhoto or Aperture.

From [My Photo Stream FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4486)

Comment: The user specifically asked about iCloud Photo Library, which is not the same thing as My Photo Stream.

Comment: the OP is asking how to EXTRACT their data, not UPLOAD their data

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do it documented on Tom's Guide

> How to Download Your Photos From iCloud
>
> https://www.tomsguide.com/us/how-to-download-icloud-photos,news-24697.html

It's also linked on this Apple Discussion

> Download all your iCloud photos
>
> https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7908422

If you're on a Windows PC it walks you through installing iCloud for Windows and then configuring it to include Photos, login with your AppleID

[image: iCloudPhotos Download photos and videos]

There is one very unsatisfactory aspect to the cloud solution which has to do with the file attributes. If you look at the image I just downloaded from my iCloud Photos the creating and modification dates are all wiped out to today's date. I have to instead rely on the image's internal metadata creation date to reconcile this. For video `mp4` files there is no such metadata. This wouldn't be so bad if Apple made the sensible choice to timestamp their filenames like you see on Android.
[image: File Attribute Loss]

Same story on my Mac
[image: Mac Get Info properties on file]